# Would a 06-08 Saturn radio fit into a 2002 LW-200?

Tags: saturn, audio

I own a 2002 Saturn LW-200, with the stock radio/CD which doesn't have an auxiliary input. I want to replace the radio with one that has aux-in, so I can get rid of my crappy FM transmitter to listen to my iPod.

Before buying an aftermarket radio, I would like to know if I can use a more recent Saturn radio as-is in my 2002 Saturn.

For example, there is one with part number 15790419 on eBay, listed as a 06-08 ION / VUE / SKY radio.

Does anybody know if that radio would fit in my 2002 LW-200 Saturn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try browsing [Crutchfield](http://www.crutchfield.com/)’s catalogue of car stereos. You might be able to infer an answer from their information on which stereos fit which cars. However, even if the dashboard spaces are the same, the wiring may be different. You might need an adaptor to connect the newer stereo to the older car's plug. Crutchfield or a stereo shop might be able to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have started exploring their site and forums to seek an answer to my question, and also took the liberty of cross-posting my question to their [forum](http://community.crutchfield.com/forums/p/21680/249098.aspx#249098). I'll update this page here when I have a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Crutchfield. I reposted my question in their forums and got a [pretty thorough answer](http://community.crutchfield.com/forums/p/21680/249181.aspx#249181). In short: the answer is that a more recent Saturn radio would probably not fit in my 2002 Saturn.