# Install 2003 Honda Civic stereo in 2000 Honda Civic

Tags: honda, civic, audio

I replaced the stereo in my car and thus have a spare 2003 Civic stereo. My friend's 2000 Civic stereo is starting to have major problems. Does anyone know if it would be possible to put the spare stereo into the 2000 Civic?

**UPDATE:** I did look at Crutchfield's website, and the radios from one model did not always occur on the other model. This doesn't seem definitive to me, but seems to imply an incompatibility.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/765/would-a-06-08-saturn-radio-fit-into-a-2002-lw-200

Comment: I think it pertains to a different car so it should stay open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many recent cars and stereos use a standard ISO wiring connector. If the 2003 stereo has done so, you should be able to fit it into the earlier car quite easily. If it is a custom Honda connector then it depends on whether they have changed the design between the cars - I wouldn't have thought they would do however.

You say the radios "did not always occur on the other model", which implies to me that some of the radios were common across both years. If this is the case, then I would expect the connectors to be the same, as they must be the same across all stereos in a given model range unless adapters are used...

The only reason I can think that they would be incompatible is if the newer stereo has additional features that require extra connections that the old one didn't. I can't imagine big car manufacturers spend money re-designing bits that hardly anyone will ever see unless they have to!

Comment: comment on last sentence: I am frequently surprised how many car parts fit only one make model year.  Parts that no one sees till they need to be replaced.

Comment: True. Stereos often seem to be the exception though, perhaps because they are frequently supplied by a third-party, so maybe the stereo manufacturers insist on a more consistent interface...